# Define more than 1 testing examples - FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, endpoint

I am working on my machine learning infrastructure with FastAPI. To test my endpoint, I would like to use more than 1 example. I can read in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#body-with-multiple-examples) that it is possible to define many examples in the `Body`, but I am getting an error.

My code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Body

api_router = APIRouter()

my_examples = {
    "normal": {
        "summary": "some summary",
        "description": "some description",
        "value": first_example}, 
    "also_normal": {
        "summary": "also_some summary",
        "description": "also_some description",
        "value": second_example
}}

@api_router.post("/my_endpoint", status_code=200)
async def do_something(input_data: my_schema = Body(examples=my_examples)) -> dict:
    """
    Description of this endpoint.
    """

    # Some function
    results = my_function(jsonable_encoder(input_data))

    return results
```

My error:

> TypeError: Body() missing 1 required positional argument: 'default'

I cannot find any information about that argument in the documentation. I tried to put `default = first_example`, but then only that example shows up (also, it is without summary and description). It also works only for 1 example when defining it in the `my_schema` using `class Config: schema_extra` as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#pydantic-schema_extra).

Is it possible to make it work and if so then how?

Comment: Does `Body(..., examples=my_examples)` work?

Comment: does `...` mean something specific? I tried to put `...` precisely as is, out of desperation, but no it did not work out - it only now gives me body with 0 when float or int, "string" when string and ['string'] when list.